Memory leakage while using shared_ptr
I've been trying to solve a problem that involves reduction of water in districts of a city. The program takes the input of numbers of district and a number of district in which the restaurant is located. The idea is for that restaurant to be the last in order of reduction (similar to Josephus problem, if I recall correctly). This is the code I've written using smart pointers:
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct District {
    int district_number;
    shared_ptr<District> next;
};

vector<int> Reduction(int N, int M) {
    vector<int> reduction_order;

    auto start = make_shared<District>();
    start->district_number = 1;
    auto previous = start;

    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        auto new_district = make_shared<District>();
        new_district->district_number = i;
        previous->next = new_district;
        previous = previous->next;
    }
    previous->next = start;

    int counter = 0;
    auto current = previous->next;

    while (current != current->next) {
        if (counter % M == 0) {
            reduction_order.push_back(current->district_number);
            auto temp = current->next;
            previous->next = temp;
            current = nullptr;
            current = previous->next;
        } else {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        
        counter++;
    }
    reduction_order.push_back(current->district_number);
    current = nullptr;

    return reduction_order;
}

int StepSelection(int N, int K) {
    if (N <= 0 || K <= 0 || K > N)
        throw domain_error("The number of districts and the ordinal number of the district are positive integers and the ordinal number of the district cannot be greater than the number of districts.");
    if (N != 1 && K == 1)
        return 0;
    int M(1);

    vector<int> reduction_order(Reduction(N, M));

    while (reduction_order[reduction_order.size() - 1] != K) {
        M++;
        reduction_order = Reduction(N, M);
        if (M >= 5 * N) {
            M = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return M;
}

int main() {
    try {
        int N, K;
        cout << "Enter the number of districts in the city: ";
        cin >> N;
        cout << "Enter the ordinal number of the district where the restaurant is located: ";
        cin >> K;
        cout << "Required step: " << StepSelection(N, K);
    }
    catch (domain_error& d) {
        cout << d.what();
    }

    return 0;
}

Here is an example output:
Enter the number of districts in the city: 10
Enter the ordinal number of the district where the restaurant is located: 4
Required step: 2

This is the correct output, so it seems like the code works fine and does the job. But also there are some memory leaks, specifically according to LeakSanitizer there are 80 bytes leaked in 2 allocations. Here is the message:
==1453486==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 40 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
#0 0x7f2ecb337587 in operator new(unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cc:104
#1 0x55c4ecd58b96 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:114
#2 0x55c4ecd587ac in std::allocator_traits, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:443
#3 0x55c4ecd58179 in std::__allocated_ptr, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocated_ptr.h:97
#4 0x55c4ecd57ade in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count>(District*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag >) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:677
#5 0x55c4ecd5718c in std::__shared_ptr::__shared_ptr>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag >) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1344
#6 0x55c4ecd56463 in std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag >) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr.h:359
#7 0x55c4ecd5543f in std::shared_ptr std::allocate_shared>(std::allocator const&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr.h:702
#8 0x55c4ecd54c8f in std::shared_ptr std::make_shared() /usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr.h:718
#9 0x55c4ecd5381e in Reduction(int, int) main.cpp:28
#10 0x55c4ecd53fc0 in StepSelection(int, int) main.cpp:70
#11 0x55c4ecd54287 in _main() main.cpp:87
#12 0x55c4ecd54415 in main main.cpp:101
#13 0x7f2ecad0e082 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

Direct leak of 40 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
#0 0x7f2ecb337587 in operator new(unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cc:104
#1 0x55c4ecd58b96 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:114
#2 0x55c4ecd587ac in std::allocator_traits, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:443
#3 0x55c4ecd58179 in std::__allocated_ptr, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > > std::__allocate_guarded, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >(std::allocator, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocated_ptr.h:97
#4 0x55c4ecd57ade in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count>(District*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag >) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:677
#5 0x55c4ecd5718c in std::__shared_ptr::__shared_ptr>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag >) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1344
#6 0x55c4ecd56463 in std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag >) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr.h:359
#7 0x55c4ecd5543f in std::shared_ptr std::allocate_shared>(std::allocator const&) /usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr.h:702
#8 0x55c4ecd54c8f in std::shared_ptr std::make_shared() /usr/include/c++/9/bits/shared_ptr.h:718
#9 0x55c4ecd5381e in Reduction(int, int) main.cpp:28
#10 0x55c4ecd53eb2 in StepSelection(int, int) main.cpp:66
#11 0x55c4ecd54287 in _main() main.cpp:87
#12 0x55c4ecd54415 in main main.cpp:101
#13 0x7f2ecad0e082 in __libc_start_main ../csu/libc-start.c:308

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 80 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).

Any ideas what could be the cause of this and how to fix this?

With previous->next = start; you make a circular list. It also introduces a loop for the shared pointers. None of them will ever have their reference counter reach zero. I haven't looked at the other code, but it feels that it might introduce even more dependencies. Try iterating over the list and print out all the shared pointer objects reference count when the function is about to return.

Also, do you really need smart pointers here? You seem to use them as a kind of garbage-collection mechanics, which is not really the purpose of them. This is a case where non-owning plain pointers and explicit new/delete is a good fit.

@Someprogrammerdude I need a circular list for this to work, or at least as far as I know. Regarding your second comment. I've already done this with regular pointers, so I wanted to try doing it with smart pointers.

@Someprogrammerdude new/delete is rarely a good fit for anything. I do use raw pointers, but rarely in containers, and never with new/delete -- if you see yourself calling new/delete, you're probably looking at situation that calls for std::unique_ptr...

And now you know why you shouldn't just use std::shared_ptr without thinking. There is always a risk of circular references. When designing data structures it is key to understand what piece of your data structure is actually OWNING the memory.  In this case I would say a City would have sole ownership of the Districts (and could just have a member std::vector` any code needing access (for a while) can get a reference to a district by asking the city for one.

Maybe use weak_ptr? I think it's use case is to eliminate circular dependencies..

If you need a singly-linked list, just use std::forward_list. Don't reinvent the wheel. Pointers have specific use-cases. You must not jump on pointers at first occasion.

Any ideas what could be the cause of this and how to fix this?  Misuse of std::shared_ptr, when what should have been used is std::unique_ptr and non-owning raw pointers.

current = nullptr;

does not do anything to the object pointed to by current, it just detaches the pointer current.
At the end of your loop in Reduction, you have current->next = current.
Break the cycle here by resetting current->next instead:
current->next = nullptr;

or
current->next.reset();


At the end of loop I put previous->next=nullptr and it fixed the problem.

You have a strong reference cycle in your code:
Lets assume Reduction(2, anything) is called.
Before for loop:

start previous are pointing to object with id: 1

for loop is executed once:

new_district points to object with id: 2
object with id: 1 next value points to 2
previous are pointing to object with id: 2

after for loop:

object with id: 2 next value points to 1

An you have strong reference cycle between objects with ids: 1 and 2 making them eternal - so memory leak.
Basically your design of data structure is wrong. Someone is proposing to use std::weak_ptr, but I do not see that your logic can consume it properly. IMO you should drop use of shared_ptr (it is overkill) at all and just use std::vector and indexes as next.
See this Herb Sutter talk for full details.
